# Squarespace site not resolving - movement from Craft/Digital Ocean to interim Squarespace site

Tags: domains, squarespace

We're switching from Craft/Digital Ocean over to Squarespace (long story, temporary fix). The urls show connected from the Squarespace side. The site did resolve initially. It seems that over time that the quits resolving with the following error:

This site can’t be reached 'website' took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall.

Any recommendations? Could it be that the other site info wasn't properly removed from Network Solutions, or perhaps something to do with a redirect?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of urls.  Feel free to disguise them using example.com

Comment: Thank you! This actually resolved. Very much appreciate your offer to assist though!

Comment: This is being closed since you indicated the issue is now resolved. Thank you for letting us know.